# How to automatically pick up current date and time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an model wherein i am collecting some data from the form. along with this data i need to automatically log in current data and time when a post request is made.

How can i get current date and time. currently I am able to get current date and time as string type in rails using strftime function.I need the data identical to how it is stored in created and updated timestamps.

Comment: `created_at`/`updated_at` are stored as time objects. You get current time by using, for example, `Time.now`

Comment: From Time.now output how can i extract only date and time portion. What should be the corresponding data type in my migration fie

Comment: `:datetime`, of course.

Comment: how can i extract time and date seprately

Comment: Why do you want them separate?

Comment: For display purposes, use `strftime`. For storing, you don't want/need them separate

Answer (score 0):

Time.current should be the same format as created_at updated_at

If it's different you can use strftime to format the Time.current